# How to concatenate a number or a compute with a string error: "Expected a number type" Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In VS Code angular project I have this warning !

> "Expected a number type" Angular

When I use data binding html attribute in template:

```
[style.font-size]="16+i+'px'"
```

Answer (score 0):

The good way is:

```
[style.font-size.px]="16+i"
```

Comment: use literal template like `${ 16 + i }px`

Comment: It doesn't work because I use data binding html attribute [style.font-size]="..."

Comment: you can use [style.font-size.px]="16+i"   instead of [style.font-size]="(16+i).toString()+'px'"

Comment: @a-morel , this is a working demo , you can  check  it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z3map8

Comment: @Ghoul Ahmed Indeed it's much better! Thank you